# Why are some datasets already loaded into RStudio when I open it?

Tags: r

Everytime I open RStudio, there are certain datasets already listed in my "Global Environment" (including hwy, HOU, chicagoFlights, etc.). Why would that happen and is there anyway to stop those from automatically loading so that my environment is empty each time I open RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

[This article on Quick R](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) may serve you some useful insight. You can actually customise the R environment on load through an init file.

I am using a Mac OS X. When I type `locate Rprofile` on my terminal, it shows

`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/base/R/Rprofile`

I edited my Rprofile to add in `dplyr` and `ggplot2` so that they are automatically loaded every time I open my R session.

```
local({dp <- Sys.getenv("R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES")
       if(identical(dp, "")) ## it fact methods is done first
           dp <- c("datasets", "utils", "grDevices", "graphics",
                   "stats", "methods", "dplyr", "ggplot2")
       else if(identical(dp, "NULL")) dp <- character(0)
       else dp <- strsplit(dp, ",")[[1]]
       dp <- sub("[[:blank:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)", "\\1", dp) # strip whitespace
       options(defaultPackages = dp)
    })
```

In your case, you may consider remove some packages in your Rprofile configuration, e.g `dataset`.

Have fun coding.